# make a particular element to be first in array

Tags: php

I've an array like this

```
$arrList = Array ( 
     [0] => Array
        (
          [master] => Array
                (
                  [id] => 3
                  [name] => Test
                )
        )

     [1] => Array
        (
          [master] => Array
                (
                  [id] => 4
                  [name] => Sample
                )
        )
  )
```

Now, I know the value of the `id`,how can I re-arrange with the particular value of `id` to be on the top..(i.e.,whatever the value of `id` that I have in a variable that should be on top of the array, if I get the value of `id` as 4 then the array should be

```
$arrList = Array ( 
         [0] => Array
            (
              [master] => Array
                    (
                      [id] => 4
                      [name] => Sample
                    )
            )

         [1] => Array
            (
              [master] => Array
                    (
                      [id] => 3
                      [name] => Test
                    )
            )
      )
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: By sorting, using usort(), but you need to be able to define the ordering rules - and you're not obviously expressing what they should be in your post

Comment: It would be easier if you post the var_export() result of the array instead of print_r()

Comment: You want to change "place" of two elements? Is that the question?

Comment: no its not that only two elements, suppose if I have 5 elements, I have a value = x, now the element having the [master][id] = x should be in the top of the array,i.e it should be the 1st element in the array whatever its position before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this code

```
foreach($arrList as $Key => $array) {
    if($id == $array['master']['id']){ //check the value with all [master][id]
         $arr[] = $array; // setting up the respective array to another array
         $iKey = $Key; // getting the key value of that particular array
    }
}
if(isset($iKey) && $iKey != NULL){
    unset($arrList[$iKey]); // removing the key value from the main array
    array_splice($arrList, 0, 0, $arr);
    //using this function setting up again the array to the 0th index,
}
```

for any other index value, mention as second parameter in above function, suppose if you need to have as third index then it should be..

```
array_splice($arrList, 3, 0, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['master']['id'] == $b['master']['id']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['master']['id'] > $b['master']['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}


$a = Array ( 
        0 => Array   (
          'master' => Array
                (
                  'id' => 3,
                  'name' => 'Test',
                )
        ),

     '1' => Array
        (
          'master' => Array
                (
                  'id' => 4,
                  'name' => 'Sample',
                )
        )
  );

usort($a, "cmp");


print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array with a special sort function. The code is:

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){ return $b['master']['id']==4; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have created example here

http://codepad.org/z4oI9KHk

Comment: it's not that sorting by ASC or DESC., see my last comment with eg like (value = x).